# jQuery focus after onblur using "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, onblur

I have several fields that need to check for a minimum value after onblur and return to the field if the value is not correct. $(this).focus() does not seem to work.

```
$(".PartMin").blur(function()
{
    var Value = this.value.replace("$", "");
    if(Value < 115)
    {
        alert("Value cannot be less than $115.00");
        $(this).focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Recommend **not** doing intrusive validation (popping up an alert) on blur. Let the user move around fields, and provide non-intrusive feedback (colors, etc.), and only intrusive feedback when they try to confirm an action using the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting focus in blur callbacks is often problematic. I've found introducing a delay helps:

```
$(".PartMin").blur(function()
{
    var Value = this.value.replace("$", "");
    if(Value < 115)
    {
        alert("Value cannot be less than $115.00");
        var element = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
          $(element).focus();
        }, 50);
    }
});
```

[Live Example](http://output.jsbin.com/deduxoneyo) (doens't work with Stack Snippets because of the snippet UI).

---

**But:** I strongly recommend **not** doing intrusive validation (popping up an alert) on blur. Let the user move around fields, and provide non-intrusive feedback (colors, etc.), and only intrusive feedback when they try to confirm an action using the data.

Comment: Did the trick, although, in this instance, your side comment was even more beneficial. Since the user is told the minimum at the top of the table, I simply color the background of the cell to indicate the error. Thanks